# ironport appliance can't receive messages from specific sender

Tags: email-server, ironport

I use the ironport appliance as my mail gateway.
I can't receive all messages a  specific sender address sends me. Some get delivered, some don't.

I have added exceptions in the "Sender Verification Exception Table", but it still gets stuck somehow.

This is the log of the ones that get delivered:

[image: Delivered]

This is the log of the ones that DON'T get delivered:

[image: Not delivered]

What can be happening?

Comment: Not trying to sound rude...but wouldn't it be easier to contact Ironport's support and get this resolved quickly?

Comment: Not trying to sound rude, I would if I had that support. If you can't help don't post anything ok?

Comment: brgsousa that kind of attitude won't endear people to helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the comment...

The message was aborted on the sending side, possibly a timeout or some kind of connectivity issue.

You would need to create an injection debug log for their sending IP and capture the message flow to decipher really what is happening.  But if you don't know how to interpret the debug log or how to create one, then it would be difficult for you to deduce what is really happening.  This is where Ironport's help would be needed most, or you can look at the [management guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/esa/esa7.0/daily_guide/ESA_7.0.1_GA_Daily_Management_Guide.pdf) and see how the Injection Debug Logs are used, but it isn't very descriptive in the Guide.